# Alea implementation

Tags: javascript, random, statistics, revealing-module-pattern

The following is an implementation of the Alea random number generation approach by Johannes Baagøe, reworked from the rot.js implementation by dropping all the pesky underscore prefixes in the variables and making those variables truly private.

The code has passed through JsHint and js-beautify, please address any and all aspects. The `alea` object is intended to be used as a singleton.

```
alea = function Alea() {
  //2^-32
  var frac = 2.3283064365386963e-10,
    states = [],
    s0, s1, s2, c;

  /*jshint -W004 */
  function seed( seed ) {
    s0 = ( ( seed || new Date().getTime() ) >>> 0 ) * frac;
    s1 = ( seed = ( seed * 69069 + 1 ) >>> 0 ) * frac;
    s2 = ( seed = ( seed * 69069 + 1 ) >>> 0 ) * frac;
    c = 1;
    return this;
  }

  function random() {
    var t = 2091639 * s0 + c * frac;
    s0 = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    c = t | 0;
    s2 = t - c;
    return s2;
  }

  function normal( mean, stddev ) {
    var u, v, r;
    do {
      u = 2 * random() - 1;
      v = 2 * random() - 1;
      r = u * u + v * v;
    } while ( r > 1 || !r );
    var gauss = u * Math.sqrt( -2 * Math.log( r ) / r );
    return( mean || 0 ) + gauss * ( stddev || 1 );
  }

  function percentage() {
    return 1 + Math.floor( random() * 100 );
  }

  function pushState() {
    states.push( [ s0, s1, s2, c ] );
  }

  function popState() {
      if( states.length ) {
        var state = states.pop();
        s0 = state[ 0 ];
        s1 = state[ 1 ];
        s2 = state[ 2 ];
        c = state[ 3 ];
      }
    }
    //Take care of the initial (mystery meat) seed
  seed( 3717022350 );
  //Return the module
  return {
    seed: seed,
    random: random,
    normal: normal,
    percentage: percentage,
    popState: popState,
    pushState: pushState,
  };
}();
```

Some research:

- The original site went down, but there is the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20111119022126/http://baagoe.org/en/wiki/Better_random_numbers_for_javascript):
- There is an implementation very close to the original [here](https://github.com/coverslide/node-alea/blob/master/alea.js):
- There is an [implementation](https://github.com/ondras/rot.js/blob/master/src/rng.js) also in rot.js.

Comment: Could you add some links to "canonical"/original implementations? Just to compare and contrast

Comment: Done, especially the wayback link is worth reading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is decidedly not my area of expertise so I've focussed on "the easy parts": Style and API.

But I think I've found a bug in the `seed` function:

If called without any arguments (or a falsey argument), the following happens:

```
// s0 is defined using a fallback/default value for `seed`
s0 = ( ( seed || new Date().getTime() ) >>> 0 ) * frac;

// but said fallback isn't stored, so the following *always* equates to:
//   s1 = (seed = 1) * frac  =>  s1 = frac;
s1 = ( seed = ( seed * 69069 + 1 ) >>> 0 ) * frac;

// and thus this *always* equates to:
//   s2 = (seed = 69070) * frac  =>  s2 = frac * 69070;
s2 = ( seed = ( seed * 69069 + 1 ) >>> 0 ) * frac;
```

Again, I don't dare speculate what impact this has on the overall randomness. The behavior's consistent though, so everything still works. But I assume it isn't quite as it should be, as you've basically got 2 seed values.

I'd propose unpacking some of those lines:

```
function seed(seed) {
  seed = (seed || new Date().getTime()) >>> 0;
  s0 = seed * frac;

  seed = (seed * 69069 + 1) >>> 0;
  s1 = seed * frac;

  seed = (seed * 69069 + 1) >>> 0;
  s2 = seed * frac;

  c = 1;
  return this;
}
```

There's certainly some repetition there, but it seems clearer to me. I've also changed the use a whitespace a little (particularly inside parentheses), but that's just personal preference.

Speaking of falsey arguments, it'd be nice to accept zero as a valid seed, without defaulting to the current time (numeric zero seems like a valid enough seed value, if a little unimaginative). One could for instance do;

```
seed = (typeof seed === 'number' ? seed : Date.now()) >>> 0;
```

The use of `Date.now()` is of course predicated on the runtimes you're targeting. I mostly used it to save some letters here.

*Edit: Forgot this, but the above line won't work as intended if `seed` is `NaN`, since `typeof NaN === 'number'`... yes, it's bizarre. Anyway, an `isNaN()` check might be useful.*

From here on it's mostly readability suggestions and such:

You've named the wrapper function `Alea` although it's not really a constructor and could just be an anonymous IIFE. I'd probably just do the latter.

`frac` should perhaps be named `FRAC` as it's treated as constant (even if it isn't actually *constant*). I can't describe it better than "fraction" or I might suggest a different name altogether.

In `random()` you've got a magic number in the form of `2091639`. I'd suggest sticking that in a variable, just to label it. If of course there's a good label to give it other than "a number". Same goes for the `69069` in seed.

I'd also move the assignment of `c` up a bit just have nicely aligned `s0, s1, s2` lines:

```
function random() {
  var t = 2091639 * s0 + c * frac;
  c = t | 0;      
  s0 = s1;
  s1 = s2;
  s2 = t - c;
  return s2;
}
```

*Aaah...* Ok, yeah, that's really OCD'ish :)

Speaking of OCD: The whitespace in `normal()` irks me a little. The `return(...` line especially, makes `return` look like a function invocation. Again, personal preference; I just think it looks odd.

`percentage()` seems incapable of returning zero. Any reason to not use `Math.round()` instead of `floor + 1`? (Also interesting that you've previously used the `| 0` trick instead of spelling out `Math.floor`.)

And there's this line:

```
//Take care of the initial (mystery meat) seed
seed( 3717022350 );
```

Wouldn't it be more natural to let `seed` default to the current time? It'd let the generator be "more random" out of the box, without requiring the user to explicitly call `seed` as the first thing.

By the way, it might be nice to add a function to return the seed value. Whether it's the fixed number above or the current time, it could be nice to be able to extract the seed value, if you haven't set it yourself.

Lastly, while I like the `pushState`/`popState` way of managing the generator, it introduces some complexity in usage, I think.

For instance, calling `pushState` does nothing on its own; you still have to call `seed` separately. Meanwhile `popState` *may* fail silently. Being a singleton, there could also be some confusion about whether to push a state or just reseed the generator's current state. It's impossible for a piece of code to know if some other code has reseeded or pushed a new state, so you might end up with some belt-and-suspenders code to *always* push a state, reseed to a known value, do stuff, and pop state again if the generator is used in several places.

`pushState()` and `popState()` might at least return `this`, to allow some simple chaining, like `seed()` does. Or simply make a `pushSeed` function, which sounds lurid, but you can just say it's an homage to [The Roots' 2002 hit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojC0mg2hJCc)...

On the whole though, I'd probably prefer a non-singleton implementation where "state" is simply a generator instance. Each instance could still have a state-stack of course.

Here's a light refactoring, which'll return an object (regardless of whether you call `new Alea()` or just `Alea()`). I've left out the push/pop state stuff, but again, you could keep that in there. I've added a `getSeed` function, just as an example.

```
function Alea(initialSeed) {
  var FRAC = 2.3283064365386963e-10, // 2^-32
      T = 2091639,
      states = [],
      seedValue,
      s0, s1, s2, c;

  function seed(seed) {
    seedValue = (seed || new Date().getTime()) >>> 0;
    seed = seedValue;
    s0 = seed * FRAC;
    seed = (seed * 69069 + 1) >>> 0;
    s1 = seed * FRAC;
    seed = (seed * 69069 + 1) >>> 0;
    s2 = seed * FRAC;
    c = 1;
    return this;
  }

  function getSeed() {
    return seedValue;
  }

  function random() {
    var t = T * s0 + c * FRAC;
    c = t | 0;
    s0 = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = t - c;
    return s2;
  }

  function normal(mean, stddev) {
    var u, v, r, gauss;
    do {
      u = 2 * random() - 1;
      v = 2 * random() - 1;
      r = u * u + v * v;
    } while ( r > 1 || !r );

    gauss = u * Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(r) / r);

    return (mean || 0) + gauss * (stddev || 1);
  }

  function percentage() {
    return Math.round(random() * 100);
  }

  // Seed this "instance"
  seed(initialSeed);

  // Return an object
  return {
    seed: seed,
    random: random,
    normal: normal,
    percentage: percentage,
    getSeed: getSeed
  };
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I noticed your great answer 3 years after... My apologies!